# why i can't see the alert on my basic html (with js file ) page ?

Tags: javascript, html

just start learn web dev ..

i created two files 
   - html file 
   - js file

the js file i wrote code:

```
function func1()
{
    alert("alert message");

    //document.writeln("document write line");

    //console.log("this is log message");

 }
```

The html file code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="basicFile.js"/>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        func1();
    </script>
</body>
```

Why the alert does not popup ? 
also the doc.writeln does not work.

When i write the js func1 directly on the html - its work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to close script tag differently. Do

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js" />
```

Comment: thanks !!! its work now